# Why do dynamically added servers not get checked?

Tags: config, haproxy

I am setting up HAProxy for a simple backend server. This is my `haproxy.cfg` file:

```
global
  user haproxy
  group haproxy
  stats socket /var/run/haproxy.sock mode 660 level admin expose-fd listeners
  daemon

frontend webapp
  mode http
  bind *:80
  default_backend webservers

backend webservers
  mode http
  balance roundrobin
  server s1 web1:5000 check
  server s2 web2:5000 check

listen stats
  bind *:9999
  mode http
  stats enable
  stats uri /stats
  stats hide-version
```

Now, after sending requests to port `:80` and starting my HAProxy container I pull up the HAProxy stats page and see the following: [image]

Notice how, even though I did not explicitly defined it in the `haproxy.cfg` file, layer 4 health checks are being performed on these servers. Now I use the Runtime API to add a server, explicitly:

```
echo "add server webservers/s3 10.89.1.47:5000 check" | socat stdio /var/run/haproxy.sock
```

and also switch the state to ready,

```
echo "set server webservers/s3 state ready" | socat stdio /var/run/haproxy.sock
```

Then I see the following in the HAProxy stats page:
[image]

The requests are now being load balanced across the new server, which is great. However, I noticed that its status is 'no check', indicating that no health checks are being performed on the new server. I'm confident that my added server is up and running, and handling requests effectively. Nevertheless, I would like it to have the same status as the default servers, which undergo health checks. Can you please advise why there are no health checks being performed on my new server, while the default servers are being checked?

I already tried adding the `option tcp-check` but this did not work. Also, as I understand, I should not set `option tcp-check` if my mode is `mode http`.